# PHP 5.3 static keyword

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference between self and static keyword in static method.

I do understand that you could not extend static methods, you could, but they would always reference to parent method.

And static keyword inside static method solves that.

So does it means I can forget about self, and joust use static from now on?
Or there are cases where I could use self?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really cant explain it better or give better examples than the doc on [Late Static Binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). So its not that you should always use one or another, its a question of whether you want/need to resolve the call up the inheritance chain (`static::theMethod()`) or whether you want the traditional behavior (`self::methodName()`). I'm sure there are use cases for both.